# How to avoid that these bootstrap labels break into next line?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, label

I am fighting with these bootstrap icons. My wish would it be that they dont wrap into next line, especially if there is enough space as there would be in the shown example.

Secondly what would I have to change that the label gets it space if it needs it, as it might be wider than the given space shown in the image?

breaking label:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you use Font Awesome or Glyphicons at the end of the label.

This can be fixed by changing the **CSS** of `label` class as below:

```
.label {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Referenence](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13219#issuecomment-39003117)